# Compiling with line numbers in Play for Scala

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

When I try to debug my Play for Scala application in Eclipse, I get the following error when I click on Debug in Eclipse (the break-point is already selected). How to compile in Play with line numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to ignore this message, just click on "Don't tell me again", it will stop on the break-point anyway.